# Extract string based on given parameter values

Tags: mysql, substring

Extract string based on given parameter values
I have below table:

ID         Skills

1          Java-16, Oracle-10, pl/sql-9,BI-19, Perl-10

2          Oracle-10, sql-9, Java-20

3          Java-10, C-10,Oracle-50

My sql is parameterized query, when I enter input values like  :skill1=Java and :skill2 = Ora then my output should as below:
Note: The above column Skills is always have values with above two parameters as it is returning based on subquery (by comparing like operator), now I need to extract the values only with the parameter values as below.

value of the column is having concatenating skills with number separated with ',' to another skill as shown

the output should be like this:

ID  Skills

1        Java-16, Oracle-10

2        Oracle-10, Java-20

3        Java-10, Oracle-50

Comment: Look at using a better database structure. Its possible but not scalable or reliable as you currently have it

Comment: @exussum  values are not direct from the actual table, it is in the final result set, as I mentioned 'Skills' column is returning by concatenating values as I show to end user number skills and exp the particular candidate has in a single row, the database was designed properly.

Comment: post how the table actually looks then because ID, Skills as its set out not is not a "good" way to store it

Comment: You can use like clause.

Comment: How do the parameters refer to which fields are to be brought back? Are they just looking for comma separated values that start with the passed value?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, breaking up the comma separated list is as follows (assuming that you just want skills that start with one of the passed parameters)

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Skills, ',', 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10), ',', -1))
FROM sometable,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Skills, ',', 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10), ',', -1) LIKE :skill1
OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Skills, ',', 1 + units.i + tens.i * 10), ',', -1) LIKE :skill2
GROUP BY ID
```

This is not likely to be fast and it would probably be better to redesign how you source and store your data to avoid this situation.

Comment: seems it is a bit complex, I am trying to redesign the logic,  Thank you all for your time.